# Error en Evento

Tags: c#, eventos

El código ejecuta bien la lista sugerida de colores la primera vez,pero al seleccionar un elemento de la lista con cualquier letra ya no muestra mas la lista de colores. Le llevo dando vueltas pero no puedo encontrar el error, al parecer mi error esta en la linea `TxtColor.Text = LbxNombre.SelectedValue.ToString();` del evento `KeyDown` ,algo estoy pasando por alto pero no se que puede ser, se agradece mucho la ayuda.Saludos

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SqlConnection Conector;
    SqlCommand Comando;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CargarListaPorbase();
    }

    private void CargarListaPorbase()
    {
        Conector = Conexion.ObtnerConexion();
        Comando = new SqlCommand("Select NOMBRE from Color ", Conector);
        dr = Comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Lista.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        foreach (string foo in Lista)
        {
            LbxNombre.Items.Add(foo);
        }
        Conector.Close();
    }

    private void TxtColor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {        
        TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;              
        if (t.Text.Length > 0) { LlenarListBox(t.Text); }
    }
    private void LlenarListBox(string t)
    {
        LbxNombre.Items.Clear();
        var a= Lista.FindAll(s => s.StartsWith(t));
        foreach (string foo in a)
        {
            LbxNombre.Items.Add(foo);
        }           
    }
    private void LbxNombre_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TxtColor.Text = LbxNombre.SelectedValue.ToString();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de tu formulario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que al usar la base de datos Sql tomaba los espacios en blanco a la derecha al convertirlo en lista.